# Repeat loop once a second

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a while loop that needs to repeat once a second, and I have no idea how to do that.  I have never even used Java's time module or whatever it is called.

The basic loop is shown below.  Can anyone give me a tip on how to do this?

```
while (!isOver()) {
   // do some work
}
```

Comment: @benjamin.d  Should I put that in the body of the loop just before the end, or in the while() statement?

Comment: In the body. Check answers below

Comment: Thanks.  cmd's answer should work, but NetBeans is not picking up Thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this code snippet can help you out. It´s a scheduled timertask that will repeat the run() method every 1 second. Your can add whatever you want there.

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() 
{ 
    public void run()  
    { 
         .... //Whatever inside your loop will be executed every second
    } 
}; 

.... 

Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: When Java finally supports closures then solutions that look like this will be a lot more common.

Comment: It´s nice to use them in Android. I think it´s a neat solution for that kind of problematic. But you are totally right @JasonSperske.

Comment: Following [the syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) it might look like this: `(new Timer()).scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{.../*will be executed every second*/}, 0, 1000);` I can't wait :)

Comment: I really have to take a closer look at Groovy, it's like Java + all the good stuff from other languages

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42017/discussion-between-axierjhtjz-and-jason-sperske)

Answer (score 2):

```
while (!isOver()) {
    // do some work
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); /* 1000ms or 1 second */   
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        // handle
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do I need to import anything?  NetBeans is not picking up Thread.

Comment: Nope. YOu dont need to import anything

Comment: Oh, it says I need a Try statement.  I will put one in and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a thread, though depending on how fast your computer is, and how much work it needs to do for each iteration of the loop, it might not be perfect.

Each program has one thread at all times. If it doesn't, it's not a process. This is your main thread, it comes to "life" when your program starts, and dies when your program terminates. There is a static method on Thread called sleep(int ms). This suspends the processing of the thread until it's parameter (ms) milliseconds have elapsed. So Thread.sleep(1000) would suspend the thread for one second, then resume.

Suspending the main thread for one second each time looks like this:

```
while(!isOver()) {
    // Do stuff
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Deal with exception here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. There is another way to create threads, but for this purpose it's way too long and drawn out..

PS You need the try/catch because sometimes the System can interrupt your thread, and that will cause an exception. A simple e.printStackTrace() should let you know when it happens, but you might want to deal with it more explicitly for any production application.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void time() {
    while (! isOver) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Do nothing, just loop
        }
    }
}
```

And then start that on another thread so your main thread will continue:

```
new Thread(this::time).start();
```

Comment: Why make it sleep for a minute?

Comment: Thanks, but the Deitel brothers have not taught me try yet.

Comment: I cut-and-pasted the code from real code (that waits a minute)

Comment: I assume `this::time` is Java 8? Surely you don't wish to introduce that yet to a person new to Java..

Comment: Well, I am not exactly new, I just need an introduction to timers.  I knew Try from C++, but I have not reached it yet in Java, and I have several classes on my hands, so I can work as fast as I did in C++.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are tons of ways to accomplish what you are looking to do. Here is another way. I tend to shy away from Timers if your code can throw exceptions as it will stop the Timer from running again. Something like this will work with a few less gotchas.

```
ScheduledExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

e.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Or if you wanted to do a sleep you could try:

```
while(!isOver) {
  //DO WORK

  try {
    //Be careful if you are holding any Locks they will not be released
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Do nothing, just loop
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is just a small simulation of the Tortoise and Hare race that has the loop repeat once a second showing where they are, and it will probably never be run again, so I think it is fine for now.